# Logon via Remoptedesktop (randomly) not allowed, but works with IP instead of name

Tags: rdp

it's a company environment. DNS name resolution ist fine (really), all PC are part of the same domaine.

If i want to connect from a PC to another using the name of the target computer (with or without domaine does not change anything) it throws a error "mit den Anmeldeinformation konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden"/"no logon possible with that credentials"
If i try to connect to the remote machine with a IP instead of the target computer name, it just works.
It also works when i access the target machine via a RDP-Gateway.

As i told already, DNS name resolution is fine.

RDP Target and RDP client did not show any error in the logs.

The PCs are W10 21H2 and MS Server 2016 on actual patch level.

The problem has happened some days ago for the first time and it seems to spread now.

Any idea?

Comment: There have been reports of some recent Windows update affecting RDP in several ways. The "spreading" is probably due to endpoints being updated at different times. KB5018410 KB5018411 etc. I've seen reports of issues with UDP, saved credentials, and credential delegation not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. This p[roblem started in November 2002. We have not updated our clinets machines from 2 years.